# Why isn't my spring component accessible to the WebApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, blazeds

I have a spring component which was used as a flex-blazeds endpoint (using `@RemotingDestination`) and I now need to reuse it as a REST endpoint.

What I did was create an additional rest servlet (of type `DispatcherServlet` of courser) in addition to the existing blaze-ds servlet I had.

I then wanted to access the same components using REST (hence my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/12181090)) and I found that I'm getting a 404.

My rest-servlet.xml configuration file looked something like:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>
```

And my `ContextLoaderListener` uses all my spring context files, which included the compontent-scan of those components.

Since the flex-servlet had no problem accessing these @Component beans which were scanned by the global context I assumed that the rest-servlet will also had access to them and I just need to add the annotations to the components.

The strange part was that when I explicitely added the component-scan for the package where these components reside then the rest call worked.

This meant that these component beans were being created twice, once for the global context (as it scans a config file containing this scan for the flex servlet) and one for the rest-servlet context (I verified this with a simple static counter and a lock on the class).

My question is why can't the rest-servlet see the beans the flex-servlet can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's true that the servlet appcontext can *access* the beans from the `ContextLoaderListener` appcontext, those beans will not be consulted when mapping HTTP calls to controllers. All controller beans must be declared (or scanned) directly in the servlet's appcontext, else they will be ignored.

I suggest that you separate the REST entry point annotations (i.e. `@RequestMapping`) from your BlazeDS ones. For example, take your `UserService` class from your other post: create a `UserController` class, put the REST annotations on that, and delegate from `UserController` to `UserService`. `UserController` would be declared in the servlet app context, and injected with the `UserService` from the `ContextLoaderListener` context.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Can you refer me to a resource specifying this spring decision ("those beans will not be consulted when mapping HTTP calls to controllers")?

Comment: @Ittai: No, not really.  That's just the way it works, I don't think the documentation states it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Spring Web context and define a DispatcherServlet, which will be a child context for the one loaded by ContextLoaderListener.

It is DistpatcherServlet that should load your rest-servlet.xml, not ContextLoaderListener. Otherwise, the guys whom you call "servlets" and who, in fact, I assume, are **controllers**, just won't get the requests from your client.

You can read about all this stuff here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

This is a standard way of doing Web-related things in Spring, and you definetely need to follow it.

Comment: Hi, why do you think I'm not using the dispatcherservlet? I specifically indicated I'm using it. I'd appreciate it if you reread my question since it specifies it there

Comment: @Ittai: sorry. I guess, the "create an additional rest servlet (of type DispatcherServlet)" messed me up... Because the DispatcherServlet is not a REST servlet.

Comment: no problem. What do you mean by: "the DispatcherServlet is not a REST servlet"? Do you mean that it's just a "regular" servlet and then I can use it however I want? (that I know) or in a different meaning (like there is a spring-rest servlet)?

Comment: @Ittai: I just meant that DispatcherServlet is a general-purpose servlet, and that the REST is actually implemented by the **controller**. So, when I read "REST servlet of type DispatcherServlet", something has mixed in my head. And I thought: "Seems like I need to explain, how this stuff works." Sorry again!